# Angular 2 reSTARTable timer

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've looked everywhere, but I just can't find a solution on how to create a timer with Observable, or SimpleTimer, which I can restart from a specific value. I tried unsubscribing, and then subscribing, but it won't start from the beginning, and neither can I use `this.timer = new Observable.timer(...);`
Can anyone help me with this, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve re-startable timer for example by using `switchMap()`:

```
const timerControl$ = new Subject<any>();
const timer$ = timerControl$.switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 1000));

timer$.subscribe(i => console.log(i));

// start timer
timerControl$.next();

// re-start timer
timerControl$.next();
```

**EDIT:** Here is the version which can also stop the timer:

```
const timerControl$ = new Subject<number>();
const timer$ = timerControl$.switchMap(
    period => period ? Observable.timer(0, period) : Observable.empty()
);

timer$.subscribe(i => console.log(i));

// start timer
timerControl$.next(1000);

// re-start timer with different period
timerControl$.next(500);

// stop timer
timerControl$.next(0);
```

Comment: Thanks! And could you help me with stopping it? I've tried `timerControl.unsubscribe()` and `timer.unsubscribe()`, but they do nothing.

Comment: You should spend some time learning RxJS so at the minimum you understand how the code above works. "unsubscribe()" would work if you would call it on the subscription which is returned by the "timer$.subscribe()" method.