# Angular 5 - Service implementation for caching

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

I'm looking for a proper approach to implement Angular services.

**My Service**:

```
const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/brands/'

@Injectable()
export class BrandService {

  private brands:Observable<Array<Brand>>;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  list(): Observable<Array<Brand>> {
    if(!this.brands){
      this.brands = this.http.get(endpoint).
                          .map(response => response.json())
                          .publishReplay(1) // publishReplay(1) tells rxjs to cache the most recent value which is perfect for single value http calls
                          .refCount(); // refCount() is used to keep the observable alive for as long as there are subscribers
    }    
    return this.brands;
  }

  clearCache() {
    this.brands = null;
  }

  create(brand: Brand): Observable<Brand> {
    Object.entries(brand).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key, value);
    });
    return this.http.post(endpoint+'create/', formData)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  get(id): Observable<Brand> {
    return this.http.get(endpoint+id)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error:any, caught:any): any {
    console.log(error, caught);
  }

}
```

I managed to create a caching mechanism simply using the `publishReplay` method with the Observable object.
Now, I would like to have my service automatically updates the list every minute.
I tried using `setInterval(this.clearCache, 1000*60)` and it clears, but what I would to accomplish is to update the list and notify all subscribers every minute if the list has changed.

What's the best practice to keep up-to-date all data limiting the server requests?

**UPDATE 1 (Validator Issue)**:

As suggested by martin, I changed the list method as follow:

```
list(): Observable<Array<Brand>> {
    if(!this.brands){
      this.brands = Observable.timer(0, 60 * 1000)
                        .switchMap(() => {
                          console.log('REQUESTING DATA....')
                          return this.http.get(endpoint);
                        })
                        .map(response => response.json())
                        .publishReplay(1)
                        .refCount();
    }
    return this.brands;
  }
```

It's working fine, except with validators.

The following validator was working before:

```
private brandNameValidator(control: FormControl) {
    return this.brandService.list().map(res => {
      return res.filter(brand => 
            brand.name.toLowerCase() === control.value.toLowerCase() && (!this.editMode || brand.id != this.brand.id)
        ).length>0 ? { nameAlreadyExist: true } : null;
    });
  }
```

Now, the field remains in PENDING status.

**UPDATE 2 (Validator Solution)**:

I solved the issue using the `Promise` object:

```
private brandNameValidator(control: FormControl) {
    return new Promise (resolve => {
      let subscription = this.brandService.list().subscribe(res => {
        let brandsFound = res.filter(brand => 
          brand.name.toLowerCase() === control.value.toLowerCase() && (!this.editMode || brand.id != this.brand.id)
        )
        if (brandsFound.length>0) {
          resolve({ nameAlreadyExist: true });
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      })
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 3 (Forcing List Update)**:

Right after a new brand has been created, I would like to force the list update. I don't want to wait the next minute when I know that the list has been updated.

```
  create(brand: Brand): Observable<Brand> {
    Object.entries(brand).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key, value);
    });
    return this.http.post(endpoint+'create/', formData)
      .map(response => {
        // TODO - Need to update this.brands, but I cannot use the next() method since it isn't a Subject object, but an Observable.
        // All observers need to updated about the addition
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
Observable..timer(0, 60 * 1000)
  .switchMap(() => this.http.get(endpoint))
  .map(response => response.json())
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();
```

Comment: Your solution is working fine except with reactive form validators where the status remain to PENDING. Please see my update to check the code.

Comment: Also when creating a new brand, how can I force the list update?

Comment: Does the validator need to complete the observable? If so, then use take(1) like “list().take(1)”.

Comment: I tried with take(1), but it didn't work. However I succeed using a Promise object. Many thanks

Comment: One last question: in the create method, after a new brand has been created, how can I force the list update? I mean, how can restart the timer? Not recreating a new Observable object, but forcing the HTTP request to be sent right away

Comment: Sure, I just updated the question, see UPDATE #3. Many thanks @martin for your help

Comment: I also found this solution, but I don't know actually how to use it on my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246350/angular-2-restartable-timer

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I tend to use a elm/flux/redux/ng-rx patern to manage my service state.

I'm not sure to answer exactly your question but it would be my way of doing it (not sure everything in get() and create() works since I havn't tested the whole).

```js
type Brand = string // or more probably a more complex object...
type State = { brands: Brand[]/*, someMoreInfo: any*/ }

// Signature of Actions that can modify the state
type UpdateFn = (state: State) => State 

class MyService implements OnDestroy {
  updater$: Subject<UpdateFn> // Where you send update of the state
  state$: BehaviorSubject<State> // Where you listen to update on the state

  // Where you listen update of the brands (in the state$)
  brands$: Observable<Brand[]> 

  // Just to trigger the first update (if required before the first minute)
  firstUpdate$ = new Subject<void>()

  autoUpdateSub = null

  constructor(initialValue = { brands: []/*, someMoreInfo: {}*/ }) {

    this.state$ = new BehaviorSubject<State>(initialValue)
    this.brands$ = this.state$.pluck('brands')

    this.updater$ = new Subject<UpdateFn>()
    const dispatcher = (state: State, op: UpdateFn) => op(state)

    // Where the magic happen
    // scan and dispatcher execute the Action function received on the 
    // last state and genrate a new state that is sent inside the state$
    // subject (everyone that has subscribte to state$ will receive the 
    // state update).
    this.updater$.scan(dispatcher, initialValue).subscribe(this.state$)

    this.autoUpdateSub =
      //Force update on the fist list() or every minute (not perfect)
      Observable.merge(
        Observable.interval(60 1000),
        this.firstUpdate$.take(1) 
      ).subscribe(_ => this.forceUpdate())

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.autoUpdateSub) this.autoUpdateSub.unsubscribe()
  }


  forceUpdate(): Observable<Brand[]> {
    console.log('update')
    this.http.get(endpoint)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map((brands: Brands[]) => {
        // pass in a function that returns the new list
        return previousState => {
          const newState = previousState
          newState.brands = brands
          return newState
        }
      })
      .subscribe(brandsUpdateFn => this.updater$.next(brandsUpdateFn))

    return this.brands$;
  }

  list(): Observable<Brand[]> {
    console.log('list')
    this.firstUpdate$.next()
    return this.brands$
  }

  get(id): Observable<Brand> {
    // get the brands (launch a brand request or return the cache)
    return this.brands$
      .switchMap(brands => {
        // find the brand from the index (you have to code it...)
        const index = findBrandByIndex(id, brands)

        // if the brand is found, return it inside an observable
        // otherwise request it
        return index ? Observable.of(brands[index])
          : this.http.get(endpoint + id)
            .map(response => response.json())
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  create(brand: Brand): Observable<Brand> {
    Object.entries(brand).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key, value);
    });
    return this.http.post(endpoint + 'create/', formData)
      .map(response => response.json())
      //Optimistic response : add the brand to the store, and force refetch data
      .do(_ => {
        // Add temporary the value to the store
        this.updater$.next((previousState) => {
          const newState = previousState
          newState.brands = [...previousState.brands, brand]
          return newState
        })
        // force fetch the values from the server
        this.forceUpdate()
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error:any, caught:any): any {
    console.log(error, caught);
  }
}
```